How to avoid import issues when Sphinx docs are generated from a different directory to parent app
I want to autogenerate documentation for a python project. I managed to get a barebones pipeline working with sphinx, but the output is not very pretty and I would appreciate some guidance on how to make the output cleaner and the inputs more maintainable.
My project is organized like so:
docs
   |-- build
   |-- index.rst
   |-- conf.py
app
   |-- main_app.py #entry point that intializes everything, internal imports in .py files are relative to here
   views
      |-- view1.py
      |-- view2.py
      |-- ...
   controllers
      |-- controller1.py
      |-- ...
   models
      |-- model1.py
      |-- ...
   utils
      |-- ...
   plugins
      |-- ...

Question 1
In my conf.py file, I had to mock the imports to get it to run, like so:
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
autodoc_mock_imports = ['utils', 'models','PySide6', 'controllers', 'views', 'configs']

This is, I believe, because the import statement in the .py files are written relative to the location of main_app.py, whereas the docs are generated from inside the docs folder. While this works, it feels like a hack that will come back to bite me at some point. Is there a more graceful way to handle this issue, without having to mock the imports?

Do you have __init.py__ files inside each directory so that they become Python packages and importable?

Yes, they all have that

Try sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../app")).

That fixes most of it, but still requires mocking 'app' - but with the changes suggested in your responses to my other questions this may become a non-issue.

I'm not clear why mocking app is necessary, if the change to sys.path worked. Can you elaborate?

The other changes fixed it. I do not know why it was an issue - but it looks like I was doing many things wrong and it probably just had some weird side effects. In other words, my question was wrong.
